# Magento Error on Product Page

Tags: magento, product

We are receiving this error our Magento Product pages, and can't figure out why:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:178:"Invalid method Mxperts_Jquery_Block_Page_Html_Head::addExternalItem(Array
(
    [0] => external_js
    [1] => https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
)
)";i:1;s:2635:"#0 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/community/CorlleteLab/Imagezoom/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php(38): Varien_Object->__call('addExternalItem', Array)
#1 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/community/CorlleteLab/Imagezoom/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php(38): Mxperts_Jquery_Block_Page_Html_Head->addExternalItem('external_js', 'https://ajax.go...')
#2 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): CorlleteLab_Imagezoom_Block_Catalog_Product_View->_prepareLayout()
#3 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#4 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/product...', 'product.info')
#5 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/product...', 'product.info')
#6 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#8 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#9 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(112): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#10 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#11 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#12 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#13 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#14 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/partytim/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/partytim/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/partytim/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}";s:3:"url";s:24:"/chili-pepper-beads.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

All of the other pages seem to appear properly (product grid, checkout, cms pages, etc.)

Any idea what might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: There is an error occurring in Mxperts_Jquery_Block_Page_Html_Head with the function addExternalItem.  You should look at the function to see what it might have an error with.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to include jquery.min.js through an external link using the function addExternalItem which is failing for some reason. You may try to host the jquery file locally and include this in page.xml